# Sort a list based on the the order of occurence of that value in another list

Tags: python, list, sorting

How to sort values of A based on the order of occurrence in B where values in A may be repetitive and values in B are unique

```
A=[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5] 

B=[8, 5, 6, 2, 10, 3, 1, 9, 4]
```

The expected list is C which should contain

```
C = [5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution:

Try using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
C = sorted(A, key=B.index)
```

And now:

```
print(C)
```

Output:

```
[5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4]
```

## Documentation reference:

As mentioned in the documentation of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

> Return a new sorted list from the items in *iterable*.
>
> Has two optional arguments which must be specified as keyword
> arguments.
>
> *key* specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
> comparison key from each element in *iterable* (for example,
> `key=str.lower`). The default value is `None` (compare the elements
> directly).
>
> *reverse* is a boolean value. If set to `True`, then the list elements are
> sorted as if each comparison were reversed.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `key` in `sorted` function

```py
A=[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5] 

B=[8, 5, 6, 2, 10, 3, 1, 9, 4]

C = ((i, B.index(i)) for i in A) # <generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001CE8FFBE0A0>

output = [i[0] for i in sorted(C, key=lambda x: x[1])] #[5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort it without actually using a sort.  The Counter class (from collection) is a special dictionary that maintains counts for a set of keys.  In this case, your `B` list contains all keys that are possible.  So you can use it to initialize a Counter object with zero occurrences of each key (this will preserve the order) and then add the `A` list to that.  Finally, get the repeated elements out of the resulting Counter object.

```
from collections import Counter

A=[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5] 

B=[8, 5, 6, 2, 10, 3, 1, 9, 4]


C = Counter(dict.fromkeys(B,0)) # initialize order
C.update(A)                     # 'sort' A
C = list(C.elements())          # get sorted elements

print(C)
[5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4]
```

You could also write it in a single line:

```
C = list((Counter(dict.fromkeys(B,0))+Counter(A)).elements())
```

While using `sorted(A,key=B.index)` is simpler to write, this solution has lower complexity `O(K+N)` than a sort on an index lookup `O(N x K x logN)`.